# Tastypie model field named "format"

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using tastypie and I have a unique situation. My model has a field named "format" so when I try to make a call to the related API and pass format=json, I get this error:

> The 'format' field does not allow filtering.

Other than renaming my model field, is there another workaround for this?

Comment: Did you set 

filtering = {'format' : ALL }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 'format' is hard-coded in `tastypie.utils.mime.determine_format()`. You could override `Resource.determine_format`:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
       def determine_format(self, request):
        """
        Used to determine the desired format.

        Largely relies on ``tastypie.utils.mime.determine_format`` but here
        as a point of extension.
        """

        # Determine your format and return it.
        # This is the default implementation.
        return determine_format(request, self._meta.serializer, default_format=self._meta.default_format)
```

Comment: There is actually a pill-request going on right now: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/703 Now is your chance to weight-in on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, `?format=json` in querystring is just a workaround. I never rely on it. The correct way is to sent the header `content-type: application/json`.